# How can I detect if there's a new docker image without using docker pull?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to pull and restart a docker service everyday at the same time but only if there's a new image available. Is there a docker command that returns true where I can run my update service?

Eg something like

```
docker new-update-available myname/myimage && ./myupdateandrestart.sh
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only need two commands (or a very simple shell script):

```
docker-compose pull
docker-compose up -d
```

The pull retrieves all updated images defined in your docker-compose.yml. And the up will restart any containers if they are running on older images, but otherwise leave a running instance of your application alone.

Answer (score 3):

There may be a false detection using *pull* when using multiple instances of same image on the machine (i.e. I've got multiple gitlab runners which I want to periodically upgrade if newer image is available). So create a script like `is-newer-docker-image-available.sh` with following content:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
  echo "Usage: ${0} IMAGE INSTANCE" >&2
  exit 1
fi
if [ -z "${1}" ]; then
    echo "Error: the IMAGE argument is empty." >&2
    exit 1
fi
if [ -z "${2}" ]; then
    echo "Error: the INSTANCE argument is empty." >&2
    exit 1
fi
docker pull "${1}"
IMAGE_DIGEST=$(docker image inspect --format='{{json .Id}}' "${1}" | tr -d '"')
INSTANCE_DIGEST=$(docker inspect --format='{{json .Image}}' "${2}" | tr -d '"')
test "${IMAGE_DIGEST}" = "${INSTANCE_DIGEST}"
exit $?
```

which returns 1 if pulled digest is different from yours instance digest.
For example, to check if instance `runner0` is older then latest gitlab-runner image:

```sh
if ./is-newer-docker-image-available.sh "gitlab/gitlab-runner:lastest" "runner0"
then
  docker stop runner0
  docker rm runner0
  docker run -d --name runner0 ... gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
fi
```

**UPDATE** : the hash value from `docker pull` is not image ID but the image digest, so I've updated the code to pull the image and inspect pulled image to obtain the image ID which is used in the instance inspect data as the *Image* item.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just run `docker pull`, and then only restart your service if you pulled an update. Something like:

```
if docker pull myname/myimage | grep -q "Downloaded newer image"; then
    ./myrestart.sh
fi
```

Comment: My docker image building process uses a base image from ECR, it takes a lot of time to pull that image, I want to reduce that time, so using docker pull to check if it is updated will not help.

Comment: @ShashankGarg why not? docker pull first checks the digests of the local and remote image and pulls only when they differ. also, if the layer of the base image did not differ docker doesn't pull it a second time